# Adverb of time position in a sentence

Tags: adverbs, time

I would like to know which of the following sentences is correct:

> Ideally, we should leave tomorrow early

OR

> Ideally, we should leave early tomorrow?

I know an adverb of time comes after the verb or object and usually at the end of the sentence by I'm not quite sure in this sentence.

I would really appreciate if someone would help me with this.

Comment: It depends on how you stress the two words. And whether you parse _leave early_ as a single constituent, or whether the _early_ is associated with _tomorrow_ as a phrase. There are a lot of options, which writing doesn't distinguish among. Word order is a blunt instrument compared to intonation, rhythm, and stress- like a bass drum solo.

Comment: Usually, if a word like ***yesterday, today, tomorrow*** is being used "adverbially", and is *further* modified by a straightforward "adverb of time" such as ***early, late***, we place the true adverbial *before* the noun used adverbially. *He arrived **early this morning**. I'm working **late tonight.***

Answer (score 1):

'Early tomorrow' would be more usual, but if the speaker wishes to stress that the departure must be very early in the day, they might say

> We should leave tomorrow - *early*.

Answer (score 0):

**Early** is not an adverb of time, it is an adverb of manner. **Tomorrow** is an adverb of time: these are usually (*usually* does not mean "always") the last element.

Answer (score 0):

*Ideally, we should leave early tomorrow* has more than a single reading:

1. *Ideally, we should leave early tomorrow.* ['early tomorrow' together specifies the ideal time, compare '[on] Friday morning'.
2. *Ideally, we should leave early tomorrow.* ['tomorrow' specifies the or one day when an early departure is best; compare 'Ideally, we should leave early tomorrow and on Friday, though we can have a lie-in on Thursday'].

Kate's paraphrase 1'. *Ideally, we should leave tomorrow – early.* is a stressed variant of the first reading above. But it is only idiomatic with the parenthetical format and associated significant pause (signified by the dash) in speech. Otherwise, 'early tomorrow' being cohesive, 'tomorrow early' is unidiomatic.

In [2] (paraphrase 'Ideally, when we leave tomorrow it should be early') 'leave early' is cohesive and  *'leave tomorrow early' sounds like tomorrow is being left.

Note the third possibility:

3. *Ideally, we should leave early – tomorrow.* ['tomorrow' now is what some would consider an appositive of 'early', restating with greater precision, 'early' now meaning 'early in the week/holiday/conference' say].